# Why can't I read this file on a remote server in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I launched a couple servers in AWS and I want to read the contents of the a file using Powershell.

On server 1 I create a file called `App_configuration.txt` and placed in the root of `c:\`.

The file has just 2 lines in it:

```
<Path>C:\GoodToGo</Path>
<Path>C:\GoodToGo2</Path>
```

I'm trying to access the file with this command using the remote IP of the server. The `xx.xxx.xx.xxx` is supposed to be the remote IP:

```
Get-Content -Path "\\xx.xxx.xx.xxx\c$\App_configuration.txt"
Get-Content : Cannot find path '\\xx.xxx.xx.xxx\c$\App_configuration.txt' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-Content -Path "\\xx.xxx.xx.xxx\c$\App_configuration.txt"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (\\xx.xxx.xx.xxx\c$\App_configuration.txt:String) [Get-Content], ItemNot
   FoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetContentCommand
```

I can RDP into the remote server and list the file:

```
PS C:\> ls C:\App_configuration.txt


    Directory: C:\


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
-a----         3/2/2021   4:12 PM             51 App_configuration.txt
```

I am not the same user on my local machine as the one that can log into the remote machine. The server I am trying to access is in AWS, and I am trying to access it from my local machine.

Why can't I read this remote file with this powershell line?

Comment: I cannot quite remember if PS may throw 'Cannot find path...' when the user does not have access - nevertheless could you add to the question if the same user is trying to read the file with PS as logged in with RDP?

Comment: Are administrative shares disabled on the target machine? Look for the Value `AutoShareWks` with a value of 0 in the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters`

Comment: @Dávid Laczkó ok I will update the post with that info. thanks!

Comment: @Dávid Laczkó done.

Comment: i think you may be seeing the classic "double hop" problem. the elevated part of your user token is not passed to a 3rd system. so it works from A to B, but not from B to C.

Comment: You can just run the PS console in the other user's name by holding down SHIFT and right-click, then select 'Run as different user' - or using your local user read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_requirements?view=powershell-5.1.

Comment: The above is based on assuming your local user doesn't have access - checking this by yourself or the admin answers your last question.

Comment: OK yes, the local user doesn't have access. The only user on the remote box is an administrator account with no email address.

Comment: Eventually I will need to get this script to the point where it can do this on multiple servers. But obviously I have to get this part working first.

Comment: How much of these have been tried out?: https://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/

Comment: I followed all the steps in the howtogeek article. The commands are still failing: https://pastebin.com/8m4r6m0q

The server I'm trying to access is in AWS. I'm not sure if it makes a difference.

Comment: Ok, I'm going out on a limb here as I don't have access to a Server and/or AWS but could the "c$\App" in the path be causing a problem? you might want to try using -LiteralPath vs -Path and enclosing the path in single quotes vs double quotes.

Comment: Sadly, no luck after applying the steps in the how-to-geek link above and using that. It works locally on the remote server but not from my local server. I tried -LiteralPath with single quotes and had no luck with that. Thanks anyway!

Comment: I think you might want to consider transferring this question to a site that deals with networking, like Server Fault, because I think the problem can not be fixed inside the script, and therefore not a programming issue.

Comment: Ok thanks, I will try that.

Answer (score 3):

It seems like the PowerShell cannot access the file at the specified location. So first verify that the file is there and is accessible.

```
Test-Path "\\xx.xxx.xx.xxx\c$\App_configuration.txt"
```

If `Test-Path` cannot return True, then the file cannot be found or the user doesn't have access to get the file from the server. There is no point in using `Get-Content` until the file can be found.

Also last time when I had the same issue, it was the [classic Kerberos delegate/double](https://4sysops.com/archives/using-credssp-for-second-hop-powershell-remoting/) hop issue. It can't enumerate the path because it can't delegate your credentials, so that's what I'd check first. Try using the same method to connect to just the root of the computer - I'd expect you to get a credential error.

If you're able to resolve this problem by enabling CredSSP for second hop.

Comment: Ok I will try that. Thanks. The file is there, I posted the location of the file in the OP with the `ls` command. However I think that the problem may be networking related I will try that angle next.

Comment: @TimDunphy Of course the file is there. But accessing it by `\\xx.xxx.xx.xxx\c$\App_configuration.txt` means more than this. It means that you need to have enabled administrative shares on your remote machine, which is not the default on machines that are not domain joined. Further more, as you are trying to access it with your local user, this user must have the proper access rights on the share and on the NTFS ACL of the files, which is also not default. So does this `Test-Path` command return true or false? Can you open this exact path in the explorer of your local AND your remote machine?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, what happens if you try this:

```
$server = "xx.xxx.xx.xxx"
$user = "$server\your_User_on_xx.xxx.xx.xxx"
$passw = ConvertTo-SecureString 'your_password_on_xx.xxx.xx.xxx' -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential $user, $passw

Invoke-Command $server {
    Get-Content "C:\App_configuration.txt"
} -Credential $cred
```

Comment: Is your server domain joined? Are you a local administrator of the remote server? Is PowerShell Remoting enabled on the server?

Comment: Also is it possible to `icm xx.xxx.xx.xxx {cat "c:\App_configuration.txt"}` ?

Comment: I don't have anything listening on port 443. But I do for the powershell port: 5985

 `Test-NetConnection xx.xxx.xxx.xxx  -Port 5985


ComputerName     : xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
RemoteAddress    : xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
RemotePort       : 5985
InterfaceAlias   : Ethernet
SourceAddress    : 192.168.1.25
TcpTestSucceeded : True`

Comment: I didn't setup anything on port 443 or 80 yet. But I do have those ports open on the security groups.

Comment: powershell remoting is enabled on the server, I am not the same user on my local machine that I am on the remote aws server. The server is not joined to any domain.

Comment: I ran those commands from the remote server in AWS. When I use the public IP the command fails:

`icm $server {cat "C:\App_configuration.txt"} -Credential $cred
[xx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Connecting to remote server xx.xxx.xxx.xxx failed with the following error message : Access is
denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AccessDenied,PSSessionStateBroken`

Comment: But if I run it with the local IP from the remote server the command works.

Comment: Ok, this is good! Now we know you can reach the remote host through WinRM. Access denied probably means the `$user` is not a local administrator on the remote host. Did you check that? Also here you may find some useful info: https://gist.github.com/cmcginty/f1e559e16305bdd667f6

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create access permissions on server 1 for the root of C, which is not the default setup.

To grant access to just the root, run this from an adminstrator account:

```
ICACLS "C:\" /grant:r "Authenticated Users"
```

If you want to grant access to the entire drive, use:

```
ICACLS "C:\" /inheritance:e /grant:r "Authenticated Users"
```

The "Authenticated Users" group should include powershell remote users as long as you have enabled powershell remoting, which appears so based on the error message.